Extract jwt token from RefreshingOAuthToken
Moving from springboot java to kotlin and http4k.
I found
    fun provideOauthClient(
    @Named("baseHttp") baseHttp: @JvmSuppressWildcards Function1<Request, Response>,
    @Named(OAUTH_CLIENT_ID) clientId: String,
    @Named(OAUTH_CLIENT_SECRET) clientSecret: String): @JvmSuppressWildcards HttpHandler {
    val clientCredentials = Credentials(clientId, clientSecret)
    val handler =   ClientFilters.RefreshingOAuthToken(
        oauthCredentials = clientCredentials,
        tokenUri = Uri.of("/token"),
        backend = baseHttp,
        oAuthFlowFilter = ClientFilters.OAuthClientCredentials(clientCredentials),
        gracePeriod = Duration.ofSeconds(1) ,
    ).then(baseHttp)

now I would like to expose a route that returns to the caller the jwt generated from RefreshingOAuthToken. On SpringBoot I managed using ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager. Is there an equivalent for http4k?

There isn't really a built-in way to get at the token - you can use an atomic reference in a filter quite easily though and intercept the token as it gets sent:
        val token = AtomicReference<String?>()
        val newHandler = Filter { next ->
            { req ->
                token.set(req.header("Authorization"))
                next(req)
            }
        }
        .then(handler)

